# Чего я не понимаю в докере (процессы, и как докер работает на низком уровне)

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Уважаемые господа,
я уже несколько раз задавал вопросы на тему докера, и вроде бы научился им пользоваться - на уровне базовых задач: построение и запуск моих приложений в контейнерах, прокидывание томов в контейнеры (для хранения состояния), простейшая оркестрация при помощи docker compose и т.п.

Также, я понимаю общую картину: есть "вызовы уровня ядра". Как я понимаю, docker server транслирует любые вызовы из запущенного контейнера в эти "вызовы уровня ядра". Благодаря этому, я могу на одной машине запустить внутри одного контейнера centos, внутри другого - ubuntu, а внутри третьего - alpain, и всё это будет работать.

При этом если я спрошу версию ядра командой `uname -r` на хосте и в контейнере - то мне покажется *одна и та же* версия.

А если я прошу "версию OS" командой `cat /etc/os-release` - то информация на хосте и в контейнере может  быть разной, так как контейнер содержит специфические версии программ, библиотек и т.п, то есть всего, что идёт уже "выше ядра".

Также, я понимаю кардинальные отличия докер-контейнеров от виртуальных машин.

Но вот что мне остаётся непонятным.

*Процессы.*

Я считаю кол-во запущенных процессов командой `ps -A --no-headers | wc -l`

Когда я на своём игрушечном сервере под убунтой считаю кол-во запущенны процессов, получается цифра 184.

Я возьму простейший Dockerfile, состоящий из одной строки `FROM Ubuntu 20.04`
Запущу его командой

```
    docker run --entrypoint "/bin/bash" --name u20 -it ubuntu20-img
```

просто запущу убунту в контейнере, а контейнер - в интерактивном режиме

Счетчик процессов на хосте покажет после этого 187 процессов - на три больше.
Сетчик процессов внутри контейнера показывает... 3 процесса.
И я даже понимаю, какие именно: это bash, ps и wc

Вопрос: а почему так мало? Ведь у меня, как-никак, целая убунта?

Почему она, будучи запущена в контейнере, довольствуется одним единственным процессом?

Логику и соотвествие идологии докера "один контейнер - одна функция - один процесс" я здесь вижу.

Но не понимаю, чем именно запущенная в контейнере убунта - в смысле своих процессов - так отличается от той, которая работает на хосте.

Вообще, хотелось бы немного подробнее прочитать про то, *как докер работает на низком уровне* -как происходит запуск контейнера, что происходит при выполнении `docker exec` и т.п.

Я попрбовал книжку "McKendrick R., Gallagher S. - Mastering Docker. Third Edition", посмотрел несколько видео по докеру и прочитал штук двадцать статей. Но они все построены по одному и тому же образцу "разница с VM - преимущества - команды создания контейнеров" - и погнали, погнали в сторону сборки, оркестрации и использования. В сторону того, как *использовать* docker. Про то, как он *устроен* и что просиходит на уровне системы при выполнении команд - никто не пишет.

Не могли бы Вы направить меня к правильным источникам, в которых эти моменты объяснены?

Comment: `все построены по одному и тому же образцу "разница с VM ...` - я тоже столкнулся с этой маркетинговой чушью. Многие ответы для себя нашел благодаря этому видео https://youtu.be/hdVNKmru3LM?t=434

Comment: @TotalPusher - супер, спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рассмотрим простой пример, когда запускается один контейнер:

```
docker run -ti ubuntu /bin/bash
```

С точки зрения ОС - это обычный процесс, к которому применены определенные настройки с целью:

- ограничить доступные этому процессу ресурсы (т.е. память, время CPU, IO и т.п.)
- изолировать процесс от других процессов запущенных в ОС
- изолировать файловую систему ОС от нашего процесса

Для этого используются механизмы реализованные ядром линукс:

- cgroups (control groups): позволяет настраивать для процесса ограничения по потребляемым ресурсам, а еще ставить процесс на паузу и заново запускать.
- namespaces: эта фича позволяет создавать пространства имен для системных ресурсов таких как pid-ы (идентификаторы процессов), сетевые интерфейсы, порты, идентификаторы пользователей/групп и др. Подробнее как это работает - ниже.
- ufs (union file system): позволяет несколько файловых систем объединять в одну. Используется, чтоб можно было "поверх" read-only образа файловой системы, скажем того же образа ubuntu, добавить новый "слой", который можно изменять.

Все эти возможности доступны в ядре линукса и их можно использовать в своих целях. docker - это такой фронтенд, который дает удобный интерфейс для того, чтоб всеми этими возможностями изоляции и контроля пользоваться удобно.

### Пространства имен (namespaces)

Пространство имен позволяет изолировать системные ресурсы. Например, pid-ы, если процесс запущен в отдельном пространстве имен pid-ов, то он может видеть только процессы из этого же пространства имен. Т.е. при системном вызове к ядру "дай мне список всех процессов" он увидит только те процессы, которые запущены в том же пространстве имен. Системный вызов тот же, он в себе реализовывает эту логику фильтрации.

Также важный момент, что идентификаторы в каждом пространстве свои, т.е. и в пространстве "по-умолчанию" и в созданных дополнительно могут быть процессы с идентификатором 1 и это будут разные процессы.

Аналогично есть пространства имен для пользователей. Т.е. процессу может быть назначено отдельное пространство имен, к котором существуют свои пользователи (и в том пространстве другой пользователь будет root-ом).

Так же и для портов. Процессу может быть назначено свое пространство имен, в котором процесс может использовать порт 80, при том, что в ОС порт 80 может уже быть использован другим процессом, но эти порты не пересекаются, так как они в разных пространствах имен.

> почему так мало? Ведь у меня, как-никак, целая убунта?

В том контейнере у вас нет "целой убунты". Т.е. у вас нет всего функционала, что дают те 184 процесса. Например, там нет процессов, которые следят за тем, чтоб процессы-демоны были запущены. Обычно в этом нет необходимости в силу специфики того, для чего используется контейнеры. Но если это будет необходимо, то вам придется самим запустить их внутри контейнера.

> не понимаю, чем именно запущенная в контейнере убунта - в смысле своих процессов - так отличается от той, которая работает на хосте

Тут все зависит от того, что вы называете "убунтой". В примере выше с запуском bash, у вас в контейнере запущен один процесс. С точки зрения ОС ("хост" системы - пишу в кавычках, потому что это я поясняю для лучшего понимания, на самом деле тут нет никакой хост и гостевой системы, как в VM) это просто один процесс, но которому назначены свои пространства имен, чтоб его изолировать от других процессов и файлов.

По сути убунту в контейнере это файлы, которые находятся в файловой системе образа, из которого запущен контейнер. Т.е. там есть программы именно из дистрибутива ubuntu (а не, скажем, из alpine) и их можно запускать внутри контейнера.

Comment: Роман, спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. Я в общем - уже после написания вопроса - прокрутил все известные мне факты в голове и пришел примерно к такой же картине. Тем более, что про все механизмы, про котрые Вы написали - я тоже читал, они упоминаются при описании докера. Но приятно получить подтверждение!

Comment: Также, спасио за то, что дополнили ответ еще немного и ответили прямо на мои вопросы. я за это время тоже пришел к такой же "картине мира". Вообще, классная штука этот докер!

Answer (score 1):

Тут само понимание хромает, докер это не виртуальная машина. С родни докер ближе к jail (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Jail) чем к VM. Просто оно симулирует не окружение 1 приложения, а целую экосистему определённой OS. Если пояснять на пальцах, то Docker это по сути своей эмулятор который через hypervisor симулирует OS.

Если хочется понять как под капотом?! - то стоит почить документацию на тот-же jail. Просто что-бы понять основу основ. Потом уже читать документации на hypervisor. И тогда всё само по себе раскроется.

**На основе базовой ОС (Тип 2, V)**
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Гипервизор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80)

Так прям на пальцах не пояснишь, это не разработка одной группы учёных, это скорее достояние человечества. В 90х люди научились сажать в Jail отдельные программы, потом появились всякие Poket Edition, потом началась эра эмуляторов, после полноценных виртуальных машин, потом людям захотелось что-бы виртуальные машины смогли взаимодействовать с основной ОС и появилась Hyper-V, и на её основе уже построили Docker.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ, на самом деле, мне кажется, я довольно близок к пониманию. Меня немного сбивает то, что в docker по сути нет "загрузки" - всех этих init'ов, то есть как бы запускатся один процесс в изолировванном окружении, и со своей собственной файловой системой. Немного удтвляет, что эти основы опущены в тех книгах по докеру, которые мне попадались. Если юольше никто ничего не напишет-завтра отмечу Ваш ответ как решающий мою проблему :-)